# Ahocorasick search tree return index out of bound

Tags: python, string, string-matching, aho-corasick

I used the python package ahocorasick(https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/ahocorasick/) for text matching for the state name here:

```
import ahocorasick
states = {
    'AK': 'Alaska',
    'AL': 'Alabama',
    'AR': 'Arkansas',
    'AS': 'American Samoa',
    'AZ': 'Arizona',
    'CA': 'California',
    'CO': 'Colorado',
    'CT': 'Connecticut'
}

def LoadKeywords(keywords):
    #Keyword should be a list
    tree = ahocorasick.KeywordTree()
    for k in keywords:
        tree.add(k)
    tree.make()
    return tree

keywordLong = states.values();
keywordLongTree = LoadKeywords(keywordLong);
```

Then I try to do search

```
keywordLongTree.search("Alabama")
```

it returns

```
(0, 7)
```

Which is fine and legitimate, but when I do

```
keywordLongTree.search("I don't know why this happen")
```

it should returns a NONE object but it returns:

```
(145331, 145335)
```

Has someone faces this situation before? why this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same issue. It should be the defect of the module. After all, it hasn't been modified since 2005. I used https://code.google.com/p/esmre/ instead. It worked find. Give it a trial!

Comment: Good job, Charles. It helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking for one library like this in python for a long time.